# Node red error: npm ERR! Invalid tag name

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I have a problem.

When I install a library in node red, the following error appears:

npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "" ~ "2.30.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

So what I do is go look at the package.json file of my project and indeed, it has strange characters in the dependencies and it looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-red-dashboard": "\"~\"2.30.0"
}
```

What I do at this point is delete the strange characters, looking like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-red-dashboard": "2.30.0"
}
```

With this I reload the project and it works normally but, the problem is that I always have to do this in all my projects and it is very annoying.

I also clarify that it used to work for me, but one day the error simply began to appear. I tried reinstalling everything but the problem continues, how do I solve it?

i am using node-red:2.0.5 nodejs:16.6.2 npm:7.20.5

Comment: What version of Node-RED / node.js and npm are you using? There was a bug in one 1.3.x release that caused this. So make sure you're on the latest 1.3.x release, or better yet, 2.0.5

Comment: node-red: 2.0.5
nodejs: 16.6.2
npm: 7.20.5